# Using pathlib/os.path etc correctly

Tags: python

I was wondering how to use the os.path and pathlib correctly. I'm supposed to search for a directory(which I already did) and then after that enter a letter and space and it will decide what it will do.

import os
import os.path
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

```
def search_files():
    directory = input()
    exist = Path(directory)
    if exist.exists():
        return directory
    else:
        print("Error")
        print("Try again: ")
        return search_files()





def search_characteristics(directory):
    interesting = input()
    exist = os.path.exists(directory)
    if interesting[0] == 'N':
        return os.path.join(directory, interesting)
    else:
        print("Error")
        return search_characteristics()
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory = input()
    search_files()
    search_characteristics(directory)
```

For this as you can see, search_files looks for a directory which works.
The next part is the one where I'm confused. Basically after it searches for a directory, C:\Program Files or something, I would enter N in the new line to search for what I want in the directory.

Say like

> C:\Users\Desktop\stuff
>
> N something.txt

The N would look for the exact name of the file.

Am I doing it correctly or is there another way to do it?

Comment: `search_files` doesn't work correctly! You need to use methods on the `Path` object to discover things about it. So, instead of `if exist:`, which is always `True` because its just a `Path` object, do `if exist.exists():`.

Comment: `os.path.join(directory)` isn't very interesting. Only use it when you want to join multiple path components.

Comment: I changed it to exist.exists, but I'm still getting the same error which is >    directory = os.path.join(directory)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'directory' referenced before assignment

Comment: That unbound error means exactly what it says. You haven't assigned anything to the `directory` variable so python can't use it.

Comment: Does directory = os.path.join(directory) not work? I put the directory on tthe search_files() method.

Comment: @tdelaney What should I replace the .join(directory) so that it works?

Comment: Remove the join completely. The question is where `directory` comes from. Perhaps a parameter to the function call? `def search_characteristics(directory):`.

Comment: @tdelaney Would the following work? I updated the code in my original post.

Comment: You get the directory name from `search_files`    ... I'll post a few fixes.

Answer (score 0):

This script will do what you want. Along with using the result of your directory search function for the next call, I also changed the compare to use `.startswith` so that a emtpy string response doesn't crash the program.

```
import os
from pathlib import *

def search_files():
    directory = input()
    exist = Path(directory)
    if exist.exists():
        return directory
    else:
        print("Error")
        print("Try again: ")
        return search_files()


def search_characteristics(directory):
    interesting = input()
    exist = os.path.exists(directory)
    if interesting.startswith('N'):
        return os.path.join(directory, interesting)
    else:
        print("Error")
        return search_characteristics(directory)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory = search_files()
    fn = search_characteristics(directory)
    print(fn)
```

Comment: Hm I noticed something about your code. When I ran in, and entered the directory then entered N <file name> it would show the directory/N <filename>. I also noticed that when I enter a number after the file name, it gives me an error. I have the actual file on the directory as well.

Comment: At this point you can scatter some prints around and see what the string is compared to what want. I wasn't sure about whether you wanted the N as part of the name, so I kept it in. You could do `os.path.join(directory, interesting[1:])` to skip the N.

Comment: Basically the N is the "action" that tells the program what to do. In this case, it's to search for the file name. I also tried the interesting[1:] and tested it out. There seems to be a space when I enter a file name assuming it doesn't give me the "error". 

 N will search will be for files whose names exactly match a particular name. The N will be followed by space; after the space, the rest of the line will indicate the name of the files to be searched for.